# Facebook Like doesn't display in modal window in non-chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, google-chrome

Stumped.

http://www.mixerman.net

I have a modal window on the index.php that displays if there's no cookie present, (and of course I do my dev in chrome, so I can find out the bad news right at the end, lol) and it works fine there, but the facebook "like" code doesn't display at all in ie or firefox.. It's not the div (I can throw static text there and it shows up, just not anything from fb, html5, xfbml, iframe or just even tacking a url to something..)

Anyone have any ideas?

I sure appreciate it!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<title>The Daily Adventures Of Mixerman | Welcome</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<!--

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}


</script>
<link href="styles/mixerman.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=265199713527696";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div id="fade">
  <div id="overlay">
    <div id="offame" onClick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'"></div>
    <div id="facebookery">
      <fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Mixerman/8900341182" send="false" width="250" height="35" show_faces="false" font="arial"></fb:like>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
var days = 30;
var advert = document.getElementById('fade');document.getElementById('facebookery');
if (readCookie('mixermanadvert')) {
    advert.className = '';
} else {
    advert.className = 'show';
    createCookie('mixermanadvert', 'yes', days);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pertinent parts of the css are:

```
#overlay {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 656px;
    height: 380px;
    z-index: 100;
    background-image: url(../images/tendollarbook.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
#offame {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    left: 571px;
    top: 42px;
    width: 55px;
    height: 55px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

#fade {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    background-color: black;
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    opacity: .80;
    filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 90;
}
#fade.show {
    display: block;
}
#facebookery {
    position: absolute;
    left: 416px;
    top: 202px;
    width: 240px;
    z-index: 150;
    opacity: 1.0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    }
```

The, the browsers have been:

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69 m - works!
Firefox 24 (lol!) - no worky!
Internet Exploder 10 - nope, no worky there either..
Safari - works!

..all on Windows 7 Pro and latest Apple OS..

Client is ok with skipping the FB "Like" part and just going to link to FB, but at this point, it's made me sufficiently insane and I need to know the answer here..

YMMV..

Comment: Could you post your code here ?

Comment: Also the versions of those browsers (not likely the issue, but throughness is awesomeness).

Comment: updated code, etc.. above, thanks!

Comment: Might just be that the JS SDK does not render the like button for elements that are not visible at the time it is initialized. Try calling `FB.XFBML.render` (passing the element reference explicitly for performance) after you made the element visible.

Comment: Thanks CBroe, that sounded pretty reasonable, but still no bueno.. doesn't render any of it..